# Multiple OR terms in WHERE clause

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Ii am building a poor-man's search engine for in-house use. Back when I was doing this sort of thing using MySQLi or a pgsql db in code, I would write something along the lines of this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";
$WC = array();
foreach($columns as $col )
{
  $WC[] = $col ." like '%".$term."%'";
}
$sql .= ' WHERE ('. implode(') OR (', $WC). ')';

return $sql;
```

which would concatenate a number (unknown) of column names with the search term. The resulting SQL looking somewhat like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE (title like '%kids%') OR (publisher like '%kids%') OR (author like '%kids%');
```

Fairly crude but effective to a point. Having a small and well known data set allows this sort of thing to be quite useful.

However...

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to append an arbitrary number of OR clauses to a DB::table('books')-> ... construct.   Documentation completely skirts this sort of construction.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `orWhere` repeatedly on the query object:

```
$query = DB::table('books');

foreach ($columns as $column)
{
    $query->orWhere($column, 'like', "%{$term}%");
}

return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use [MATCH AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) for that search.